# Should I return after using a function?

Tags: python, function, return

Is there any practical differences between using:

```
def some_function():
    print('Hello!')
    return()
```

and:

```
def some_function():
    print('Hello!')
```

I know that `return` isn't required, but is it bad pratice to *not* return after a function has been called?

Comment: Python functions always return: when `return` statement is missing, `None` will be returned implicitly. In your first example you're returning a tuple, that's probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `return` is not a function; it is a statement. There is no need to add the parenthesis.

Functions in python without a return statement return `None` by default. An empty `return` statement does the same, so there is no difference.

```
>>> def foo(): return
...
>>> foo()
None
>>> def bar(): pass
...
>>> bar()
None
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use return statement, your function returns None. It is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both functions return `None`, the latter does is implicitly the former explicitly.

Comment: The zen of python (`import this`): Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

A bare `return` statement is useful in one situation: when you want your function to stop running before it would otherwise do so. For example:

```
def loop_example():
    for some_item in some_sequence:
        # do something
        if some_condition:
            # no need to continue for some reason
            return
```

If that's not the case, it's just visual clutter.